# How to optimize Regex expression performance in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to find out a string in thousands of files with different patterns. My Regex is working fine and it is returning what I want to. But the problem is with the performance. It is taking more than 8 hours to search all the files ( more than 100,000 files). Is there any way that I can optimize this?

My goal is to identify all the sql objects (with/without schema name) in any vb/c#/powershell files/projects.

My regular expression and combinations I am trying are in the below link
[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/vODKg8/1)

I want to identify the strings in this format in any file

```
[dbo].xyz

dbo.[xyz]

[dbo].[xyz]

"dbo.xyz"

"[dbo].xyz"

"dbo.[xyz]"

"[dbo].[xyz]"
```

And the below is my powershell snippet

```
get-childitem -Path "$( $SearchPath )"  -Force -recurse | Where-Object { ($_.Extension -eq '.bas') -or ($_.Extension -eq '.cls') -or ($_.Extension -eq '.sql') -or ($_.Extension -eq '.cs')-or ($_.Extension -eq '.csproj')-or ($_.Extension -eq '.vb') -or ($_.Extension -eq '.cshtml') -or ($_.Extension -eq '.ps1') -or ($_.Extension -eq '.psm1')} `
                | Select-String -Pattern """(\[)?($( $SchemaName ))?(\])?(\.)?(\[)?[^a-zA-Z_\s\@\$\/,-]$( $ObjectName )(\])?[^a-zA-Z.//-]""?" `
                | select-string "^\s*$", "^\s*'", "^\s*#", "^\s*//", "^\s*/\*", "^\s*\*.*(?:\*/)?\s*$", 'Headers' -NotMatch `
                | Select Path, LineNumber
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your `(\[)?(dbo)?(\])?(\.)?(\[)?[^a-zA-Z_\s\@\$\/,-]xyz(\])?[^a-zA-Z.\/-]"?` supposed to match? Please explain the specifications rather than posting simplified sample strings.

Comment: How would you describe the rules to "*identify all the sql objects (with/without schema name) in any vb/c#/powershell files/projects*"?

Comment: The below are the possible ways a programmer can use table/view/stored procedure/function in C#/VB/Powershell code  dbo.xyz
[dbo].xyz

dbo.[xyz]

[dbo].[xyz]

"dbo.xyz"

"[dbo].xyz"

"dbo.[xyz]"

"[dbo].[xyz]"

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Maybe that a performance problem  lays in a regex itself, maybe somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can do that with a much simpler regex.

Also, instead of using a lot of `($_.Extension -eq '.something')` Where-Object statements, use `-Include`. This will gather the wanted files much faster:

```
$SearchPath = 'D:\Test'
$Includes   = '*.bas','*.cls','*.sql','*.cs','*.csproj','*.vb','*.cshtml','*.ps1','*.psm1'

Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchPath -Recurse -Include $Includes -File -Force |
    Select-String -Pattern '"?\[?\w+\]?\.\[?\w+\]?"?' |
    Select-Object Path, LineNumber
```

Result something like:

```
Path              LineNumber
----              ----------
D:\Test\Blah1.ps1          2
D:\Test\Blah2.sql          6
D:\Test\Blah3.bas          4
```